# Global visual studio font size setting?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, accessibility

I was trying to increase my font sizes in Visual Studio. The problem I ran into is that they have it broken down into a whole lot of individual categories. What I need is to make everything bigger by about 30% or so. Is there a way to do that without going through all of the different categories one by one?

Furthermore, there is no easy way to see the default for a particular setting. So if I lose my place, I can't easily tell if a particular one has been increased or not.
[image]

Comment: If that is necessary then it becomes pretty likely that you want to increase the monitor DPI, affects everything.

Comment: It should honour window settings from what I remember so you could just change it there if it doesn't mess everything else up for you? `Settings > Ease of Access > Display` - other than that does this help? https://superuser.com/a/737074